# Assert PHPUnit that an object has an integer attribute

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm using PHPUnit and I have to check a `json_decode` result.
I have an object containing an integer attribute as you can see in the debugger view :

[image: Debugger view of my object]

When I do this :

```
$this->assertObjectHasAttribute('1507',$object);
```

I get an error :

```
PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertObjectHasAttribute() must be a valid attribute name
```

My `$object` is an instance of `stdClass`

Comment: Are you calling `json_decode` in the test or the SUT ? Also note that 1509 !== 1507 - which is shown in the screenshot, the object (apparently) _doesn't_ have an attribute named `1509`. You'll probably need to restructure your test as [PHPUnit won't work with numeric attributes](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/src/Framework/Assert.php#L1111-L1113).

Comment: sorry @AD7six, it's a typo... And yes the JSON is in the test_case code, my function returns JSON

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A numeric property is abnormal, and [PHPUnit won't accept it as a valid attribute name](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/src/Framework/Assert.php#L2647-L2654):

```
private static function isAttributeName(string $string) : bool
{
    return preg_match('/[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*/', $string) === 1;
}
```

Therefore the best thing to do is *not* test if the object has an attribute, but rather check if an array has a key.

### `json_decode` returns an object *OR* an array

[As described in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

> `mixed json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = false [, int $depth = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] )`
>
> ...
>
> assoc
>
> - When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

An appropriate test method is therefore:

```
function testSomething() {
    $jsonString = '...';
    $array = json_decode($jsonString, true);
    $this->assertArrayHasKey('1507',$array);
}
```

Comment: yep thats sounds good, I was converting it to array but if json_decode makes the job I win a line :p Thank you !

Answer (score 4):

`assertObjectHasAttribute` checks that the given object has an attribute of the given name, not its value. So, in your case:

```
$this->assertObjectHasAttribute('ID',$object);
```

If you want to check its **value**, you could just use [`assertEquals`](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html#appendixes.assertions.assertEquals):

```
$this->assertEquals(1509, $object->ID);
```

Comment: BTW an attribute name that starts with a number is invalid

Comment: 1509 is the attribute, $object->1509 = "fieldValue"

Comment: @Leggendario, I know but aas I mentionned, it is valid in JSON and json_decode makes an actual stdObject with this kind of attribute ! I know that this should be invalid and this is certainly why assertObjectHasAttribute does that check ...

Answer (score 0):

Not seeing anything better, I'm gonna convert the object to an array using `get_object_vars`  and use `assertArrayHasKey` instead:

`$table = json_decode($this->request( 'POST', [ 'DataTableServer', 'getTable' ], $myData));
    $firstElement = get_object_vars($table->aaData[0]);
    $this->assertArrayHasKey('1507',$firstElement);
    $this->assertArrayNotHasKey('1509',$firstElement);
    $this->assertArrayHasKey('1510',$firstElement);
    $this->assertArrayHasKey('1511',$firstElement);`